# How do I detect specific files and use ImageMagick to make thumbnail while in a loop

Tags: bash, imagemagick, detect

I need to convert a lot of PNG files in many folders and process crop files separately to make thumbnails 100x100 px for just the "crop" files.

File naming is:

```
????_thumb.png
????_snapshot.png
????_crop.png
```

where `????` is a number.

My script so far is working to do conversions just fine,
however I need to detect when a "crop" file is reached and
then call ImageMagick and create a 100x100px thumbnail from it named ????_crop_th.png

I can't seem to figure how to detect on a wildcard ????_crop.png.

My script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

BASE64=/root/scripts/base64
logfile=/root/tester/convert_failed.txt
goodfile=/root/tester/goodfile.txt
proc_dir=/root/tester/testing
temp_file=/root/tester/temp.png
b64=/root/tester/b64.txt

cd $proc_dir
for i in *
 do
  if [ -d $i ]
       then

     for j in $i/*.png
       do
      if [ -f $j ]
        then
        #just get files name without extension
        fname=`echo $j | cut -d'.' -f1` 
        #perform operations
        cp $j ${fname}.b64
        $BASE64/base64 -d $j $temp_file

        if [ $ -eq 0 ]
          then
            cp $temp_file $j
             echo  $j >> $goodfile
             rm -f ${fname}.b64
        fi
      fi
    done
  fi
 done
 `find $proc_dir -name *.b64 -print >$b64`
 sort $logfile -o $logfile
 sort $goodfile -o $goodfile
 sort $b64 -o $b64
```

Any help is well appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things that your script does less-than-perfectly, as well as some redundancies.

I also don't see anything in your script that uses Imagemagick to generate thumbnails from `*_crop.png` files, which is theoretically what this question is about

I vote for a rewrite.  I have no idea if the following will be directly applicable to your situation, but the techniques should at least let you write better shell scripts.

```
#!/bin/bash

base64=/root/scripts/base64/base64
logfile=/root/tester/convert_failed.log
goodfile=/root/tester/goodfile.txt
proc_dir=/root/tester/testing

# The `cd` command will fail, if it fails.  (Really.)
if cd "$proc_dir"; then

    # Find all the PNGs in all subdirectories one level under our WD
    for file in */*.png; do

        # Do stuff (I have no idea what this is for...)
        if $base64 -d "$file" "${file%.png}".b64 && mv "${file%.png}".b64 "$file"; then
            echo "$file" >> $goodfile
        else
            printf '[%s] FAILED: %s\n' "${date '+%Y-%m-%d %T')" "$file" >> $logfile
        fi

        # Only make thumbnails if we need them
        if [[ $file =~ _crop.png$ ]] && [[ ! -f "${file%_crop.png}_thumb.png" ]]; then
            convert "$file" -scale 100x100 "${file%_crop.png}_thumb.png"
        fi

    done

fi
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex matching or trailing substring removal, such as:

```
if [[ "$j" =~ _crop.png$ ]]
```

or

```
if [[ "${j%_crop.png}" != "$j" ]]
```

Also note that chopping off the extension is similarly easy:

```
fname=${j%.*}
```

Another useful bash feature is recursive globbing, so you don't need the nested loops and the specialized directory handling:

```
shopt -s globstar
for j in **/*.png
```

Comment: thanks;   if [[ "$j" =~ _crop.png$ ]]  worked great, all is wrking fine now